# Задать блоку оставшуюся в родителе высоту

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, frontend

У меня `body` занимает `100vh`. Вверху страницы есть `nav` который занимает высоту, которая ему нужна. Как можно задать высоту блоку `mainContainer`, чтобы он занимал высоту до конца `body` (неважно, есть ли в нем достаточного содержимого, нет ли, или он переполнен как на скриншоте) и не выходил за его пределы? Если задавать, к примеру, `max-height: 100%` то он все равно выходит за пределы из-за наличия `nav`. На скриншоте представлена страница во всю высоту `body`. Используемые классы взяты из Bootstrap 4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<body class="bg-darkness vh-100 d-flex flex-column pb-lg-4">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid container-lg pt-lg-2 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div id="openedDialogContainer" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 h-100 bg-dark text-white p-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div class="dialogInfo text-center pt-2 pb-1 border-bottom">
          <div class="dialogInfoTitle">Mustafa</div>
          <div class="dialogInfoStatus status">online</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-2 pb-2 container-lg h-100 y-scroll">
          <div class="messageContainer">
            <div class="message bg-white text-dark px-2 py-1 rounded d-inline-block">
              <div class="messageText">Hello!</div>
              <div class="messageStatus"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="messageContainer mt-2 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="message bg-white text-dark px-2 py-1 w-75 rounded d-inline-block float-right">
              <div class="messageText text-break">Hello!HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</div>
              <div class="messageStatus float-right">
                <svg class="bi bi-check-all" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    <path d=""/>
                 </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-lg">
           <div class="row p-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control col col-sm col-md col-lg">
              <button class="btn col-auto col-sm-auto col-md-auto col-lg-auto">
                 <svg class="bi bi-triangle rotate invert" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                 </svg>
              </button>
           </div>
        </div>         
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: А если в mainContainer будет больше контента чем на высоту одного экрана, тогда что должно происходить?

Comment: @vantal контент увеличивается только за счет сообщений, поэтому в контейнере для сообщений задан класс `y-scroll` что задает `overflow-y:scroll`. он работает если уменьшать высоту `mainContainer`

Comment: А для nav можно задать фиксированную высоту?

Comment: @vantal возможно, это как-то отразится на адаптивности?

Comment: Написал в ответе пример, сли я все правильно понял. Для адаптива можете с помощью медиазапроса сделать другую высоту nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно задать высоту для `nav`, для контейнера задаете высоту 100vh минус высота `nav`

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav{
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
}
.container-fluid{
 height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<body class="bg-darkness vh-100 d-flex flex-column pb-lg-4">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid container-lg pt-lg-2 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div id="openedDialogContainer" class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 h-100 bg-dark text-white p-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div class="dialogInfo text-center pt-2 pb-1 border-bottom">
          <div class="dialogInfoTitle">Mustafa</div>
          <div class="dialogInfoStatus status">online</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-2 pb-2 container-lg h-100 y-scroll">
          <div class="messageContainer">
            <div class="message bg-white text-dark px-2 py-1 rounded d-inline-block">
              <div class="messageText">Hello!</div>
              <div class="messageStatus"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="messageContainer mt-2 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="message bg-white text-dark px-2 py-1 w-75 rounded d-inline-block float-right">
              <div class="messageText text-break">Hello!HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello</div>
              <div class="messageStatus float-right">
                <svg class="bi bi-check-all" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    <path d=""/>
                 </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-lg">
           <div class="row p-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control col col-sm col-md col-lg">
              <button class="btn col-auto col-sm-auto col-md-auto col-lg-auto">
                 <svg class="bi bi-triangle rotate invert" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                 </svg>
              </button>
           </div>
        </div>         
     </div>
</body>
```